# What are the guidelines for asking VPN or other connection-related problems?

Tags: discussion

Would my asking an [Ask Ubuntu](http://askUbuntu.com) question about guidelines for asking VPN or other connection-related questions a reasonable question to ask? Here is why I am inquiring. I got a [VPN connection problem question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/294120/how-to-debug-and-fix-pptp-vpn-client-connection) answered recently, and the answer focused more on diagnosing setup a little more than the diagnosing the logs. A more recent question has been asked, but I see no logs posted.

If I ask a question for the kinds of information that should be included in that kind of post, is that a reasonable question?